# CMake: target not in export set

Tags: cmake

I have a library `foo` which depends on `bar`. `bar` provides a nice `barConfig.cmake` upon installation.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(foo VERSION 1.0)

find_package(bar)

add_library(foo SHARED foo.c)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC bar)

install(TARGETS foo EXPORT fooTargets LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
export(EXPORT fooTargets FILE fooTargets.cmake)
install(EXPORT fooTargets FILE fooTargets.cmake DESTINATION lib/cmake)
```

This works great.  We simply `apt install bar-dev` then compile `foo`.

But since these packages are both developed by us and are related, my team would like to develop them in the same IDE session and compile them at the same time.  I want to allow that, but I don't want to change the fact that these are already deployed as seperate packages and can be built independently.

```
if (DIRECTORY_EXISTS ../bar)
  set(BAR_NO_INSTALL ON)
  set(BAR_SKIP_TESTS ON)
  add_subdirectory(../bar ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bar)
else()
  find_package(bar)
endif()
```

If `../bar/` exists, then this results in:

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "fooTargets" ...) includes target "foo" which 
 requires target "bar" that is not in the export set.
```

How can I prevent the need to export `bar` in the `foo` package?

---

I'm trying to figure out why `find_package(bar)` works, but `add_subdirectory(bar)` doesn't.  `barConfig.cmake` via `barTargets.cmake` defines `bar` like so:

```
add_library(bar SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET bar APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS NOCONFIG)
set_target_properties(bar PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "../bar/include"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_NOCONFIG "build/libbar.so.1.0.13574"
  IMPORTED_SONAME_NOCONFIG "libbar.so.1"
)
```

My guess was the `IMPORTED` property that is used when `bar` is created in the autogenerated `barConfig.cmake`.  I tried adding setting property (below), but saw no differences:

```
set_target_properties(bar PROPERTIES IMPORTED TRUE)
```

---

`fooConfig.cmake` does include the following which creates target `bar` (not `bar::bar`).

```
find_depdendency(bar)
```

---

I tried the following aliasing, hoping that an alias' inability to be exported would help me. But it still expects me to export `bar`.

```
add_library(barImported ALIAS bar)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC barImported)
```

---

I tried linking only the build interface, hoping that `bar` would not need to be exported when installed.  But that also had no effect.

```
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:bar>)
```

Comment: If target `foo` is linked (non-PRIVATE) with target `bar`, then `fooConfig.cmake` will also replicate that linkage. For make this work, `bar` should be defined. When `bar` is IMPORTED target, then CMake expect that `fooConfig.cmake`) will define `bar` target manually. E.g. with `find_dependency()` macro. If `bar` is "normal" target, then CMake wants to define `bar` by itself. This only can be done if `bar` is included into some export set.

Comment: I've added `find_dependency(bar)` in `fooConfig.cmake`, but that doesn't seem to silence cmake.

Comment: Wrap `bar` with ALIAS library ``bar::bar`` and use the alias when link `foo`. Assuming `find_dependency(bar)` creates exactly this IMPORTED target, the things will work immediately. If `find_dependency(bar)` creates `bar`, then create similar wrapping in the `fooConfig.cmake`.

Comment: `find_dependency(bar)` does create `bar` instead of `bar::bar`.  If I add `add_library(barImported ALIAS bar)`, then link to the alias, the system still expects me to export `bar`.

Comment: Yes, actually neither ALIAS nor INTERFACE library do help in avoiding the error. In case of INTERFACE it seems logical - INTERFACE library is installable. But in case of ALIAS this looks strange. Currently, I have no other ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways.  They were good ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with.  This is for an arbitrary library `foo` (dynamic and static versions plus tests) which could also be a dependency in the same manner that I import `bar`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
include(GNUInstallDirs)

project(foo VERSION 1.0)

# Options set to 
#  ON  explicitly for build machines, 
#  OFF by default for developers who build dependencies inline and only build for local use
option(FOO_EXPORT_TARGETS "Generate fooConfig.cmake for packaging." OFF)
option(FOO_BUILD_TESTS "Build and run tests. Default off for aircraft. Turn on in your IDE if developing foo" OFF)

# This is best implemented as a macro/function from an included cmake
set(BAR_ROOT "/noexist" CACHE PATH "Location of BAR for in-source building")
if (DIRECTORY_EXISTS "${BAR_ROOT}")
  add_subdirectory(${BAR_ROOT})
else()
  find_package(bar)
endif()

set(fooSources foo.c)
set(fooPublicHeaders include/foo.h)

add_library(fooObjects OBJECT ${fooSources})
target_include_directories(fooObjects
  PUBLIC
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
    "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>"
  PRIVATE
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:bar,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
)

add_library(foo       SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:fooObjects>)
add_library(fooStatic STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:fooObjects>)
target_link_libraries(foo       PUBLIC fooObjects bar)
target_link_libraries(fooStatic PUBLIC fooObjects barStatic)

set_target_properties(fooObjects foo fooStatic
  PROPERTIES
    POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
)

if (NOT FOO_EXPORT_TARGETS)
  install(TARGETS foo LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
else()
  set_target_properties(foo fooStatic
    PROPERTIES
      VERSION ${foo_VERSION}
      SOVERSION ${foo_VERSION_MAJOR}
      PUBLIC_HEADER "${fooPublicHeaders}"
  )

  install(
    TARGETS foo fooStatic fooObjects
    EXPORT fooTargets
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_INCLUDEDIR}/foo
  )

  include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

  set(configDir "${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}/cmake/foo-${foo_VERSION_MAJOR}")

  configure_package_config_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/fooConfig.cmake.in"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/fooConfig.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION ${configDir}
  )

  write_basic_package_version_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/fooConfigVersion.cmake"
    VERSION ${foo_VERSION}
    COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
  )

  install(FILES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/fooConfig.cmake"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/fooConfigVersion.cmake"
    DESTINATION ${configDir}
  )

  export (EXPORT fooTargets FILE fooTargets.cmake)
  install(EXPORT fooTargets FILE fooTargets.cmake DESTINATION ${configDir})
endif()

if (FOO_BUILD_TESTS)
  add_executable(test_foo test.c)
  target_link_libraries(test_foo foo)
  
  enable_testing()
  add_test(NAME test_foo COMMAND test_foo WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test)
endif()
```

With the following `fooConfig.cmake.in`:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

@PACKAGE_INIT@

find_dependency(bar)

if(NOT TARGET foo)
  include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/fooTargets.cmake")
endif()
```

The build machines create a debian package out of this.  This is what the `debian/rules` files look like to ensure it is compiled without any in-source building, with packaging, and with tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
#export DH_VERBOSE = 1

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- \
        -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH) \
        -DFOO_BUILD_TESTS=ON \
        -DFOO_EXPORT_TARGETS=ON \
        -DBAR_ROOT=/noexist
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I prevent the need to export bar in the foo package?

You can't, at least not without hacks (see below).

> I'm trying to figure out why find_package(bar) works, but add_subdirectory(bar) doesn't. barConfig.cmake via barTargets.cmake defines bar like so:

Because in one case, the target is imported (which can only be set on creation) and in the other case, the target is normal. Normal targets must be installed if normal targets that depend on them are installed.

The semantic issue with `add_subdirectory` is that CMake believes that any code you add this way is *first-party*. I have found that `add_subdirectory` and its relative `FetchContent` are more trouble than they're worth for installed dependencies. They're useful for build-or-test-only dependencies that do not need to be shipped.

---

One way to work around this is to use the `COMPONENT` / `NAMELINK_COMPONENT` features of the [`install()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command. Then you would set the `CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL` variable to include only the components from `foo` and not those from `bar`. When specifying components, you should avoid generic names like `development` or `runtime`, and instead prefix those names with the project name: `foo_development`, `bar_runtime`, etc.

Unfortunately, this does not affect the `cmake --build . --target install` command. You'll have to go through [`cmake --install . --component <comp>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project) or CPack.

---

A **hack** is to add the `bar` dependency to `foo` as `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>` and then re-attach it to `foo` in `fooConfig.cmake` after `include`-ing your generated target export file and finding `bar` via `find_dependency`.

Comment: Tried `add_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:bar>)` and was prepared to make some updates to `fooConfig.cmake`, but it didn't see to change anything.  But it sounds like it really isn't possible otherwise.  Instead I'm just adding `option(FOO_EXPORT_TARGETS)` which is off when people are developing locally, but on, when producing the package.

Comment: @Stewart - Well, the command isn't `add_link_libraries`, it's `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: My mistake when writing the response, yes `target_link_libraries` is what I used.

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm looking to make a small library available for open source with a couple of dependencies, and started off with the FetchContent route, and naively added an install mechanism, which failed for the reasons you explain. It looks like providing a library you need to consider the FetchContent and install (vcpkg/conan etc) routes as completely separate -- and ideally support both, unless I have it wrong?